# Obtaining the $0$th cohomology group from the Universal Coefficient Theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Suppose I have a sequence of abelian groups $\cdots C_2\to C_1\to C_0\to 0$. Then the Universal Coefficient Theorem tells us that for any abelian group, $A$, we have the exact sequence $$0\to Ext^1(H_{j-1}(C),G)\to H^j(C;G)\to Hom(H_j(C),G)\to 0$$ So, if we know the homology groups, then we can find $H^j(C;G)$ for $j\geq 1$. However, can we use this to obtain $H^0(C;G)$ as well? Would, for example, it be valid to assert $Ext^1(H_{-1}(C),G):=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is true since all negative singular cohomology is trivial.

Comment: Is that because we can extend the chain of abelian groups with a sequence of trivial groups?

Comment: Yes, you can define all the negative chain groups to be trivial. Depending on how you prove the universal coefficient theorem you might be required to do this because it is a statement about homology and cohomology of chain complexes that are bounded below.

Comment: I’ll add that negative homology groups are not a trifle, general homology theories have negative homology groups, and sometimes these theories have analogues to the universal coefficient theorem which will not be trivial like this example is.